# Does the AWS SES SMTP server automatically sign emails with DKIM?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, phpmailer, dkim, domainkeys

I am using AWS SES and PHPMAILER to handle email sending in my system.

My question is, does the SES SMTP server automatically sign my emails with my DomainKey (DKIM) or do I have to do it manually using PHPMAILER?

On one hand, Amazon declares that they sign emails with DKIM, but on the other hand I see that you can add headers and sign emails with DKIM in PHPMAILER, so I don't really understand whose responsibility it is to sign my emails with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up SES's [Easy DKIM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/easy-dkim.html), all messages sent through SES will be automatically signed. You don't need to bother with having PHP handle that.

If you're sending email from a single domain (or small number of them) this is the way to go. If you are doing something tricky (like sending email on behalf of hundreds or thousands of domains) it might be easier to handle the DKIM signing in PHP.